# How can I locally analyze SMART logs from a server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sata, fsck, smart

I have Ubuntu 10.04 server running on a desktop at home. I rebooted, and the machine was unreachable after 10 minutes or so. At this point I should have connected a console (monitor using VGA cable). Instead, I powered off the machine (held down the power button for three seconds). This time I *did* connect a console, and fsck was running. I'm guessing the box was unreachable the first time because fsck was running then too. Anyway, on the next reboot, I couldn't mount a partition on one of my two 1.5TB drives (/dev/sdb1).

`fsck /dev/sdb1` found some errors (short read? something like that) but `fsck -Cy /dev/sdb1` fixed them, and I was able to mount and use the partition.

I've since installed smartmontools and configured it to run as a daemon following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools). If I run `sudo service smartmontools restart`, the `root` user gets four emails, with these errors:

```
Device: /dev/sda, 366 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Device: /dev/sdb, 13 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Device: /dev/sdb, 28 Offline uncorrectable sectors
Device: /dev/sda, 90 Offline uncorrectable sectors
```

Both drives (all partitions) otherwise seem fine: I don't see any application errors, strange behvaior, or errors/warnings in /var/log/{syslog,messages}.

So, finally, some questions:

1. Is there any way to grab SMART logs off the box and analyze them locally using [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de)?
2. Can killing fsck midstream actually trash hardware?
3. If the drives really are ok, can I squelch/reset the SMART errors somehow?

Thanks,
-Adam

**UPDATE**: The drives are apparently healthy:

```
# smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl version 5.38 [i686-pc-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

# smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl version 5.38 [i686-pc-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:
Here is a way how I do it with disks on a 3Ware controller:

```
server $ smartctl -d 3ware,0 -a /dev/twa0 > smart.0
server $ smartctl -d 3ware,1 -a /dev/twa1 > smart.1
server $ smartctl -d 3ware,2 -a /dev/twa2 > smart.2
wks $ scp server:smart.* .
wks $ gsmartcontrol -q --no-scan --add-virtual smart.0 --add-virtual smart.1 --add-virtual smart.2
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That works well for pulling down SMART info. I ended up using `smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sda > /tmp/smart.0` and `smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sdb > /tmp/smart.1`. Analyzed locally. Looked fine, no errors.